# Switch between UITextFields when return button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistackview

Im trying to have my UITextFields switch to the next one when the return button is pressed. Here Is my code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        // Try to find next responder
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            print("success")
        } else { //if textField.text != nil {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            print("error")
    } 
    return false
}
```

I use this code all the time with other projects. However, this is an exception. I have each element in it's own stack view, and all of those stack views are in a superview stack view. Once I run the app, I press the return button and it goes to the else statement and resigns the first responder. I need it to run the `nextField.becomesFirstResponder()`
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPwQV.png)

Comment: what's the problem ??

Comment: Didn't you forget to set delegates of every text field?

Comment: I set the delegates, and the tags of the textFields. Look at the screenshot.

Comment: Never makes assumptions about the private subview structure of UI components.

Comment: What I believe the problem is, the if let statement can't find the other textFields in the superview because the superview is a stack view made up of other stack views and each textField has its own stack view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the private problem

```
if let nextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField
```

but it's problem is in performance `viewWithTag` recursively searches in subviews

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean by its a problem in performance?

Answer (score 0):

Create Outlet Collection and connect every text field to it

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
```

after in text field delegate function use this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextIndex = textField.tag + 1
    if textFields.count > nextIndex {
        let nextField = textFields[nextIndex]
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: While this might make the code work, this is a terrible solution. Never make any assumptions about the private subview structure of UI components. This code could stop working in any future iOS update.

Comment: This code does work. However, what rmaddy said about the private subview structure is what I still need help solving./

Comment: @Etiekyed try edited answer. This may be correct way how to achieve what you want to.